# How to set log level on knife winrm command in Chef

Tags: chef-infra, winrm

Need to set lower log level (debug) on chef-client that is kicked of by knife winrm.

Command currently looks like this.

```
knife winrm MY-MACHINE chef-client --manual-list --winrm-user 'user' --winrm-password 'pwd'
```

The only thing I found is verbose flag on `knife winrm` subcommand.

I want the same result as when doing `kitchen converge -l debug` during testing

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make the command `"chef-client -l debug"`? I'm more familiar with `knife ssh` than `knife winrm` but it should handle the same way AFAIK.